# View result of plotGoogleMap

Tags: r, plotgooglemaps

Similar to this question:
[Plotting UK postcodes on a map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036809/plotting-uk-postcodes-on-a-map-in-r/29038935)

I am trying to plot various postcodes on a map using the plotGoogleMaps function, however when I get to the last step e.g.

```
m <- plotGoogleMaps(UK_Map , filename='MAP_UK.html')
```

Nothing happens except for the little stop sign in the corner appearing as if something is loading.

Is anyone able to tell me how I can view the map / where I'm going wrong? I have read elsewhere that you can supposedly view the file in your working directory but unfortunately it's not there so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Please read [ask] and give a [mcve], i.e. edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42438740/edit

Comment: Can you provide a small example which produces this behavior? Also, please specify what packages you're using along with their versions.

Comment: Some plots take a long time to render - are you sure it is not still working?